Kohlberg-Mertens theorem
I am trying to understand the Kohlberg-Mertens theorem. Here is the context and the theorem. We fix $N$ a set of players and $S_i$ the finite set of actions of each players with $\lvert S_i\rvert =m_i$. We define $\Sigma_i$ to be the set of probability measure on $S_i$ i.e. the simplex of $\mathbb{R}^{m_i}$. Let $S=\Pi_{i\in N} S_i$ and $\Sigma=\Pi_{i\in N}\Sigma_i$ where $\lvert S\rvert = m$. We identify a game $G$ to its payoff functions, here for each player $i$ a payoff function lies in $\mathbb{R}^{\lvert S_{-i}\rvert\times m_i}:=\Gamma_i$, hence a game $G$ is identified to $g=(g_1,…,g_N)\in\mathbb{R}^{Nm}:=\Pi_{i\in N}\Gamma_i$. Let $\mathcal{G}$ be the set of all such payoff $g$. We define the set
$$
E=\{(g,\sigma)\in\mathcal{G}\times\Sigma :\sigma\:\text{Nash equilibrium of}\: g\}
$$
The theorem is the following

The projection $\pi : E\to\mathcal{G}$ is homotopic to an homeomorphism from $E$ to $\mathcal{G}$.

The intuition is that we can pass continuously from the graph of the Nash correspondence to the set of games. Now my question is on the proof of this result.
They start by saying this

Let $T_{i}=\Pi_{h\neq I}S_{h}$, reparametrize $\Gamma_i$ the set of all $\lvert S_i\rvert\times\lvert T_i\rvert$ payoff matrices $G_{s,t}^{i}$ by $G_{s,t}=\tilde{G}_{s,t}^{i}$ with $\sum_{t\in T_i}\tilde{G}_{s,t}^i=0$, letting $z_{s}^i = \sigma_{s}^i +\sum_{t\in T^i}G_{s,t}^i\Pi_{j\neq I}\sigma_{t_j}^j$, $(\tilde{G}_{s,t}^{i},z_{s}^i)$ can be viewed as belonging to $\Gamma_i$. 

However, it is not clear for me that that the sum in the definition of $z_{s}^{i}$ is well defined. Indeed, if I understand well (this is not defined explicitly in the paper) $\sigma_{s}^{i}$ is the probability that player $i$ choses the action $s_i$ (where $s_i$ is such that $s=(s_1,…,s_i,…,s_N)\in S$) under $\sigma^i$ , that is a scalar, while $\tilde{G}_{s,t}^i$ is a matrix.
I think that I am misunderstanding something. If you have any knowledge on this please do not hesitate.
Thank you a lot !

That "quote" is not a quote.

@MichaelGreinecker Thank you for the remark, I edited the post
